# How to create and print an array from user in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Im starting to learn Kotlin and wanted to try a little code, just to read and print an int array from the user, this is my code

```
import java.util.*

fun main(){
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    println("Enter the number of elements: ")
    var arrayInt = IntArray(scan.nextInt())
    println("Size of the array: ${arrayInt.size}")
    println("Enter the numbers: ")
    for(item in arrayInt)
        arrayInt[item] = scan.nextInt()

    for(i in arrayInt)
        print("${arrayInt[i]} ")

}
```

but when I run the code the only thing i get print is the last number I enter and some 0s, what im doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
for(i in arrayInt)
```

instead of

```
for (i in arrayInt.indices)
```

or

```
for (i in 0 until arrayInt.size)
```

then the `i` is the actual content of the array, not the array indices.

So in your case, your last line can be changed to

```
print("$i ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun main() 
{     
    val arraya = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
    for (i in 0..arrayname.size-1) 
    { 
        print(" "+arraya[i]) 
    } 
    println() 
   
    val arrayname2 = arrayOf<Int>(10, 20, 30, 40, 50) 
    for (i in 0..arrayname2.size-1) 
    { 
        print(" "+arrayname2[i]) 
    } 
}
```

Pretty sure that is how you do it

Answer (score 1):

The incorrect part of your code is this:

```
for(item in arrayInt)
    arrayInt[item] = scan.nextInt()
```

Here, `item` is *not an index*. It is a value from `arrayInt`. It means that, if the array was just constructed, every `item` will be `0`, which is the default `Int` value. Thus, what you are doing is basically:

```
arrayInt[0] = scan.nextInt()
```

`arrayInt.size` times.

---

I would suggest dropping `Scanner` entirely for such trivial task and stick with Kotlin's richer library:

```
fun main() {
    print("Please input numbers separated by spaces: ")
    val list = readLine()!!.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
    println(list)
}
```

`readLine()` will read the entire line, and may return `null` if it reaches the end-of-file as a first character. However, it won't, because we are not planning to input it - we use `!!` to tell the compiler that it will be a valid `String`, not a `String?` which may be `null`. Then we `split()` on spaces, which will yield a `List<String>` and we `map()` every `String` to `Int` via `toInt()` method.

After all, we end up with `list` value which contains inputted numbers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like

```
val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
println("Enter the number:")
val n = scan.nextLine().trim().toInt()
println("Enter array:")
val arr = scan.nextLine().split(" ").map{ it.trim().toInt() }.toTypedArray()

println(Arrays.toString(arr))
```

Comment: And the following seems to work too: `arr.contentToString()`

Answer (score 0):

To ask for user input for the size of Array and Insert Elements use this:

```
    println("Enter Size of Array: ")
        val aSize = Integer.valueOf(readln())
        *//Muhammad Salman*
        var arrayInt = IntArray(aSize)
    
        println("Enter Array Elements: (Numbers Only)")
        for (i in 0 until aSize){
            arrayInt[i] = Integer.valueOf(readln())
        }
        *// Muhammad Salman*
        println("\nElements in Array: ")
        for (x in 0 until aSize){
            print("" + arrayInt[x] + " ")
    
        }
```